# WCF Client - Missing Array Elements

Tags: arrays, wcf

With .net 4.5 and WCF i acces a dataservice.

Now for one part wcf doesn't return array elements which are in the service.

The part of the logged xml response looks like this

```
<v1:itemParts>
  <v1:itemPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="v1:foundItemPart">
    <v1:frId>1603795000</v1:frId>
    <v1:tId>509515001</v1:tId>
    <v1:date1>2015-05-19T07:15:00+02:00</v1:date1>
    <v1:sub>
      <v1:id>2006960476</v1:id>
    </v1:sub>
    <v1:aviableItems>
      <entry xmlns="">
        <key>NO</key>
        <value>14</value>
      </entry>
    </v1:aviableItems>
  </v1:itemPart>
</v1:itemParts>
```

The missing part is **aviableItems** which is generated as an empty array without items

the wsdl defined this part as follows:

```
<xs:element name="aviableItems">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="entry">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="key" type="v1:seatClassEnum"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="value" type="xs:int"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The generated type is defined like this:

```
  [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34230")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="urn:myServer.it/v1")]
    public partial class aviableItems: object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
```

I can't figure out why thy items are not generated in the array. is there a definition error in the wsdl  ?

what i can see that visual studio creates the class with the namespace **"urn:myServer.it/v1"** but in the response the service tells **xmlns=""** may this be the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that the "xmlns" Attribute in the response is wrong its set to an empty string, so the namespace doesn't  the defined in the wsdl.